# WebRTC: allow Chrome to access microphone via Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, microphone, webrtc

I am new to WebRTC and playing a bit with it. But everytime I reload the page to see latest changes in the code I have to allow Chrome to access my microphone. Now I have heard that it is possible to write an extension (app) to give this special site (right now localhost) the permission to always access the microphone. Other sites which will use the mic are not included in this extension.

Does anybody know if this is possible and maybe how to do that?

Thanks so far

Comment: If anyone is interested: if SSL is supported you can call your site via https and then there is an option where you allow / deny the access to the media where you can choose to always allow this site to acces the media (on the rightmost site).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible right now, but we're working on adding this to an upcoming version of Chrome.

Comment: Justin - do you know when Chrome Extensions will have the ability to interact with the microphone via background.html or popup.html?