# always accept webRTC webcam request

Tags: google-chrome, webcam, webrtc

I'm building a web application that uses the computer's webcam via webRTC.
The site is only running on one specific machine which will shut down and reboot once a day.

My problem is: how do I get the machine to automatically confirm the webcam dialogue once the site has loaded?

The system is OSX Leopard with the latest Chrome. Thanks already, I'm open for anything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**There is a Chrome option for that:** *(This works in both **http** and **https**)*

```
--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
```

---

**- Windows :**

```
start chrome --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
```

**- GNU/Linux :**

```
google-chrome --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
```

*Maybe this is just a matter of time, but it didn't work on my chromium on Ubuntu.
I had to get the .deb from the [google chrome website](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/).*

**- Mac :**

```
Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
```

---

This could be useful in a development/testing environment.

Comment: Mac: /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream

Comment: Thanks for the complement @PeterEhrlich. Should you want to, you can edit my answer also :)

Comment: You can put this command in a shortcut of chrome. For example for my development is use the desktop shortcut like this:
`"%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe " --user-data-dir=$(mktemp -d) --kiosk "http://localhost:52902/Default.aspx" --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream`

Comment: Is it working? I have the same problem and it is not working for me. Error: getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins.

Comment: @user1253414 "Starting with Chrome 47, getUserMedia() requests are only allowed from secure origins: HTTPS or localhost.
" https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/chrome-47-webrtc?hl=en
There may be a workaround that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 23):

**Firefox** : (You have to tell users like..)

- Go in url `about:config`
- Search `media.navigator.permission.disabled`
- dbClick or set **value** to `true`

*Tested version : 23.0 +* *(and 43.0.4 still working)*

---

**Chrome** : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16929608/622813 or use **HTTPS**

Comment: After half an hour of troubleshooting, it was a lot easier for me to just switch to firefox for this project and use the above. I couldn't ever convince chrome to allow localhost

Comment: I was looking everywhere for this FireFox option... the Mozilla help page didn't appear to include instructions for `http://localhost`. Thanks!!

Answer (score 16):

Based on what the Chromium developers are saying, there is currently no option to configure your browser to allow camera usage, unless you utilize the "Always allow" dialog - which will only be shown if the site is served using HTTPS. That means, if you serve the HTML page using HTTPS, and once confirm the "Always allow" option, it should work from there on. Here is a collection of links where you'll find answers to the same or similar questions:

1. [Chromium issue 143372: allow "always allow" for http://localhost](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?q=WebRTC&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&id=143372)
2. [WebRTC: allow Chrome to access microphone via Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088980/webrtc-allow-chrome-to-access-microphone-via-chrome-extension)
3. http://www.chromium.org/developers/web-platform-status (see section on WebRTC): "For the permission dialog: Chrome only show the "Always allow" for sites using https for increased security."
4. Discuss WebRTC Google Group: [Automatically allow Camera Access Request in webrtc enabled Chrome](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/discuss-webrtc/gthj_fKKGKM/AknAl6o-UW8J)