# Chrome shows 'URL' wants to use your microphone

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microphone, webrtc

I want to create an smartphone in web browsers, and I've done a good job till now. However, when I call, Google Chrome shows this message:

> `'http://domain'` the wants to use your microphone.

See this picture:

And this is a picture of my web-based smartphone:

However, when I call, user should click `Allow` in the Chrome's message bar. Is there any way that I ask the browser to save microphone settings for the current user, so that each time user is not asked for permission?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15999940/1165146) claims that if you use https at least chrome will only ask once. No idea if it actually works.

Answer (score 3):

You need to serve your page over https. When using https, Chrome will remember the user's choice and will not ask again.

Then if the user wants to block the microphone again, they can click on the camera icon in the URL bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `Chrome's Settings => Advanced => Content Settings => Media section`, you see that there are only two options that you can choose:

1. To be asked **EACH TIME** a page wants to access your microphone or camera
2. To disable media altogether

Thus there seems to be no option for that. It might sound logical, as you don't want hackers starting your camera and capturing your private life without permission. ;)