# How to detect if microphone permissions have been granted in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I would liked to detect whether or not microphone permissions have been granted on my site when it loads without actually running something like the following:

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: active}, 
    function(){alert('worked')}, 
    function(){alert('failed')});
```

Is there a simple API to detect whether the user has permanently granted microphone access to my application (which runs over https)?

Answer (score 33):

### Update

`microphone` has been added to the [Permission API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query) even if it's not yet available on Safari nor Internet Explorer.

<s>You could hope that it would be accessible from the permission api, but it isn't :(</s>

Perhaps in the feature this could work like the rest of this:

```
navigator.permissions.query(
    // { name: 'camera' }
    { name: 'microphone' }
    // { name: 'geolocation' }
    // { name: 'notifications' } 
    // { name: 'midi', sysex: false }
    // { name: 'midi', sysex: true }
    // { name: 'push', userVisibleOnly: true }
    // { name: 'push' } // without userVisibleOnly isn't supported in chrome M45, yet
).then(function(permissionStatus){

    console.log(permissionStatus.state); // granted, denied, prompt

    permissionStatus.onchange = function(){
        console.log("Permission changed to " + this.state);
    }

})
```

### Old answer

The only way i see it possible is if you keep track of this yourself with a key/value item in localStorage when you ask for permission.

Unfortunately it doesn't notify you when it has been changed

```
// initialization
if( localStorage.getItem('voice_access') === null ){
    // just assume it is prompt
    localStorage.setItem('voice_access', 'prompt');
}

// Then somewhere
navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, function (e) {
    // http://stackoverflow.com/q/15993581/1008999
    //
    // In chrome, If your app is running from SSL (https://),
    // this permission will be persistent.
    // That is, users won't have to grant/deny access every time.
    localStorage.setItem("voice_access", "granted");

}, function (err) {
    if (err.name === 'PermissionDismissedError') {
        localStorage.setItem('voice_access', 'prompt')
    }
    if (err.name === 'PermissionDeniedError') {
        localStorage.setItem('voice_access', 'denied')
    }
})
```

---

You could go the extra mile and build a nice little wrapper with this code above and extend/replace the permission api to handle more enum names and create a [broadcast](https://gist.github.com/inexorabletash/52f437d1451d12145264) api to tell the other tabs when it changes. but why make it so complicated...? The localStorage can't be 100% trusted. it can be changed anywhere any time both with permission and storage cleared

Comment: The above mentioned first snipet is not working for audio as you have pointed. But is there anyway we can find its status as of the location status?

Comment: Very useful @Endless. `navigator.permissions.query({name: 'microphone'}).then(...)` and `navigator.permissions.query({name: 'camera'}).then(...)` are now available in Chrome as of now ( >= 69) and return states in `granted`, `denied`, `prompt` Thanks!

Comment: I recommend to use old answer, `permissions` API only checks the browser permission. However, there is a SYSTEM PERMISSION for microphone. (you can find it on `Privacy Setting / App Permissions / Microphone). The old answer also works with system permission.

Answer (score 1):

you already got the polling method for checking permissions.
here is some information from MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.getUserMedia

and some more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC

here is an example:

```
navigator.getMedia (
// constraints
   {
      video: true,
      audio: true
   },

   // successCallback
   function(localMediaStream) {
      var video = document.querySelector('video');
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
      video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
         // Do something with the video here.
      };
   },

   // errorCallback
   function(err) {
    console.log("The following error occured: " + err);
   }

);
```

Comment: He is asking how to get the permission state, this means without getting a user media stream

Comment: You could create the media stream outside of the screen area, then you have your check and the user doesn't know/mind. Just like a back buffer canvas for a html5 game.

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.getUserMedia` is now obsolete, replaced by `MediaDevices.getUserMedia`, which returns a promise. If the promise gets rejected you get an DOMException with indication of the problem. Insufficient permissions is one of the options there.

Details here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would be helpful:

```
function isMicrophoneAllowed(){
    navigator.permissions.query({
        name: 'microphone'
    }).then(function(permissionStatus){
        return permissionStatus.state !== 'denied';
    });
}
```

Comment: maybe `permissionStatus.state === 'granted'`

Comment: This is not supported by Safari nor Internet Explorer