# Only enable mic once on runtime

Tags: javascript, microphone

I am adding voice input to a web app using `webkitSpeechRecognition` (https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#dfn-onspeechstart).

This popup asking for permission to use mic appears each time I initiate `recognition.start();` (`recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition()`) :

[image]

The users will need to use the mic several times throughout the life of the app, and I only want them to have to give their permission once.

How can I just have it show initially on web app load?

Comment: the answer in this thread is good for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993581/reprompt-for-permissions-with-getusermedia-after-initial-denial

Answer (score -1):

Using JQuery:

`$(document).ready(function(){
    recognition.start();
});`

Using pure JS:

`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    recognition.start();
});`

Comment: this will not stop the request of the permission

Comment: You can not activate the mic without the permission request. Waht you might be able to do is to keep in running in the background. And read out the data when you need it. This will however still prompt the user on loading the page.