# How to always ask for camera permissions on page reload in JS

Tags: javascript, html, permissions, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a website that has a video element in it. Now when I open this site, a popup comes that asks for access to camera and when I allow it, it saves it and hence when I refresh the page, it doesn't ask me for camera permissions. I have to clear cache or go incognito to do so. 
How can I write a JS code so that every time the page refreshes it asks for camera permissions.

Comment: May be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15999940/1456253