# Browser's audio record or microphone's permission on button click rather than on page load

Tags: javascript, permissions, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

I have user the MediaStream Recording API for recording audio using microphone, the recording works well but in case of don't allow the browser to record a voice then click on the record button it's not showing any error,

**What I want is in case of user don't allow voice and still clicks on record button browser again asp for audio recording permission.**

I have tried several options with the following code but unfortunately, it does not work, Can anyone help me out with this issue?

The same question or similar question asked on [reprompt for permissions with getUserMedia() after initial denial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15993581/5783700) but still, there is no resolution for that issue, hope for the best appropriate answer which resolve the reprompt permission popup once initialized the page.

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <section class="main-controls">
      <canvas class="visualizer" height="60px" style="display:none"></canvas>
      <div id="buttons" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <button class="record">Record</button>
        <button class="stop">Stop</button>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="sound-clips"></section>
  </div>
  <script>
    const record = document.querySelector('.record');
    const stop = document.querySelector('.stop');
    const soundClips = document.querySelector('.sound-clips');
    const mainSection = document.querySelector('.main-controls');

    stop.disabled = true;
    let audioCtx;

    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      const constraints = {
        audio: true
      };
      let chunks = [];

      let onSuccess = function(stream) {
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

        visualize(stream);

        record.onclick = function() {
          //ask for browser's audio record or microphone permission here
          if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            mediaRecorder.start();
            console.log("recorder started");
            record.style.background = "red";
            stop.disabled = false;
            record.disabled = true;
          }
        }

        stop.onclick = function() {
          mediaRecorder.stop();
          console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
          console.log("recorder stopped");
          record.style.background = "";
          record.style.color = "";
          stop.disabled = true;
          record.disabled = false;
        }

        mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
          const clipContainer = document.createElement('article');
          const clipLabel = document.createElement('p');
          const audio = document.createElement('audio');
          clipContainer.classList.add('clip');
          audio.setAttribute('controls', '');
          clipContainer.appendChild(audio);
          clipContainer.appendChild(clipLabel);
          soundClips.appendChild(clipContainer);

          audio.controls = true;
          const blob = new Blob(chunks, {
            'type': 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus'
          });
          chunks = [];
          const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          audio.src = audioURL;
          console.log("recorder stopped");


          clipLabel.onclick = function() {
            const existingName = clipLabel.textContent;
            const newClipName = prompt('Enter a new name for your sound clip?');
            if (newClipName === null) {
              clipLabel.textContent = existingName;
            } else {
              clipLabel.textContent = newClipName;
            }
          }
        }

        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
          chunks.push(e.data);
        }
      }

      let onError = function(err) {
        console.log('The following error occured: ' + err);
      }

      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(onSuccess, onError);

    } else {
      console.log('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');
    }

    function visualize(stream) {
      if (!audioCtx) {
        audioCtx = new AudioContext();
      }

      const source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

      const analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
      analyser.fftSize = 2048;
      const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
      const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

      source.connect(analyser);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I have used simple MediaStream javascript WEBAPI.