permissions policy issue in vuejs
I'm writing a vuejs application, but the camera is blocked only in Chrome, camera permission is not even requested. I get this error "violation: permissions-policy: microphone and camera not allowed".
When I received this error in my php project before, I easily solved it with http, but I don't know what I should do in the vuejs project. I added the meta tag in html, I added the iframe tag in my vuejs code, also used getusermedia but none of them worked. Can someone please explain how to apply permissions policy in vuejs? just on chrome It blocks my camera and microphone

" I added the meta tag in html, I added the iframe tag " -what exactly do you do? It's not directly related to Vue as it does nothing to do with it, it's about using browser apis at the right time

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993581

If I knew what/how to do it, I wouldn't be asking this question here anyway. If it has nothing to do with vuejs, how can this be done for a vuejs project? That was my question

See the linked question, it's pretty extensive. If you don't know how to do this in whole, it's a good point to start. Please, provide your current attempt, so it could be seen what you do wrong, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
