# With Casper.js, is it possible to accept browser permission prompts?

Tags: browser, webrtc, casperjs, functional-testing, slimerjs

I'm hoping to test WebRTC functionality in my web app. This requires accepting the browser's permission prompt for access to the Camera and/or Microphone. Is this possible to do with Casper.js and Slimer.js? I can't find anything in the documentation suggesting it's doable.

Somewhat related (similar problem, different platform): [Accept browser permission dialog with behat/mink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613828/accept-browser-permission-dialog-with-behat-mink)

Comment: I highly doubt that. PhantomJS 1.x simply has no support for it and SlimerJS doesn't expose this functionality.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I figured that was the case but since I didn't see anything about it I thought maybe someone else knew the answer with certainty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can't programmatically click the permission button, CasperJS/SlimerJS will let you use a custom profile for the automated Firefox instance you're using in your tests. At least in the case of the *WebRTC/getUserMedia* permission prompts, Firefox lets you disable them in a profile's settings.

Here's what you do. In your shell, use SlimerJS to create a new profile:

```
slimerjs --createprofile nameOfYourNewProfileGoesHere
```

Your new profile has been created in your Firefox profiles directory. To locate the directory you can either search for the profile name you just created, or go to Firefox and `Help Menu > Troubleshooting Information`. Next to 'Profile Folder' click 'Show in Finder' (or equivalent for your platform).

Your profile is a directory with a name like `asfd1234.nameOfYourNewProfileGoesHere`, inside that dir edit the `prefs.js` file and add this line:

```
user_pref("media.navigator.permission.disabled", true);
```

Now when you run your CasperJS scripts (or SlimerJS directly, I suppose -- I only tested this through Casper), you just need to specify the profile. With CasperJS:

```
casperjs test --engine=slimerjs -P nameOfYourNewProfileGoesHere nameOfYourTestFile.js
```

It's almost too easy! ;)