# How to On webcam on page load in jquery webcam

Tags: jquery, webcam

I am using [Jquery-Webcam-Plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) to capture Images. But every time when I load the page I have to click on "Allow" button of Flash file to start the webcam. I want to on camera on page load without clicking any button.

How can I do it ?

Comment: That is a browser behavior for security.

Comment: So you mean there is no option ?

Comment: There is. but not through JS - http://stackoverflow.com/q/12160174/3639582

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I found a very easy solution for this. I am answering my own question because it could be helpful for others.

I Just simply right clicked on flash file in browser and then click on settings. Then I click on allow and selected "remember" checkbox. Now my webpage is accessing my webcam automatically on page load without asking for allow every time.

Cheers ;)